# Performance difference between given queries?

Tags: java, sql, realm

I'm trying to make a method that build a `RealmQuery`.

But here's my problem. I wonder what's performance difference between given queries?

1. Selecting all records with WHERE clause.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE gender = 'M' OR gender = 'F';
```

```java
Realm.where(SOME_CLASS.class)
    .equalTo("gender", "M")
    .equalTo("gender", "F")
    .findAll();
```

2. Selecting all records with WHERE ~ IN.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE gender IN ('M', 'F');
```

```java
Realm.where(SOME_CLASS.class)
    .in("gender", new String[] {"M", "F"})
    .findAll();
```

3. Selecting all records without WHERE clause.

```
SELECT * FROM table;
```

```java
Realm.where(SOME_CLASS.class)
    .findAll();
```

**Note that column `gender` contain `M` or `F` only.**
I think all of those queries return same result, but I want to know how does it works internally and what's performance between those queries.

Thanks for your interesting and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following two conditions are functionally identical:

```
WHERE gender = 'M' OR gender = 'F'
WHERE gender IN ('M', 'F')
```

Both the first two queries would require checking the gender value for each record.  Since every record is a match, it should not make much difference whether or not there is an index as the full table will be hit regardless.  The third query, with no `WHERE` clause, also will do a full table scan, but it will not have to do any checking in the `WHERE` clause.  For this reason, all other factors being the same, I would expect the third query to outperform the first two.

But the firm answer to your question can be had by analyzing these queries on the database using `EXPLAIN` or a similar tool.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps me a lot :)